# Can Emacs operate over RDP (Remote desktop protocol)

Tags: emacs, rdp

Googling brings up only a bunch of recursive descent parsers... so, is there no chance Emacs will work over RDP? The machine on the other end is a pure Windows Server 2008 junk, nothing else installed. How'd you go about having a normal connection to such machine from Emacs + Tramp?

Comment: can you not add new services to win server? or is it firewalled except for RDP?  not sure what your use case is but tramp w/sshd or running emacs tcp server on the windows server are a couple of options

Comment: @assem Ah, sorry, I've got smb access. I didn't know what my share name was, so assumed I wasn't able to access it. Now its all good. Thanks.